# Вращение персонажа в зависимости от направления

Tags: разработка-игр

Есть игра в которой персонаж двигается влево, вправо, вверх (вперёд) и вниз (назад) При этом персонаж должен вращаться в зависимости от направления движения. Вращается он только по одной оси (игра с видом сверху).

Вопрос: как проще это реализовать?

PS. В переменной `angle` записан угол в градусах.

Comment: Что из себя представляет персонаж?

Comment: @hedgehogues, просто прямоугольник с позицией, размером и углом поворота.

Comment: т.е. нужно повернуть координаты прямоугольника на угол fi?

Comment: @hedgehogues, нужно определить угол в зависимости от направления.

Comment: @hedgehogues, но вращение должно быть плавным. Вот в чём проблема.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. У нас в распоряжении есть 2 точки: p0, p1, которые отвечают противоположным вершинам 4-ка. Откуда берётся направление, как оно задаётся? У нас есть исходное и конечное направление.

Comment: @hedgehogues, нет, есть логические переменные `left`, `right`, `up`, `down`. По ним и определяется угол.

Comment: @hedgehogues, например вправо-вверх up == true, right == true

Comment: Т.е. может быть всего 4 состояния?

Comment: @hedgehogues, ещё диагональное движение, 8

Comment: В чём Ваша проблема? Вам нужно рассмотреть несколько случаев.

Comment: @hedgehogues, нужно реализовать плавный поворот персонажа в ту сторону в которую он направлен, направлений 8. влево, вправо, вверх, вниз, и диагональные.

Comment: В таком случае необходимо поворачивать на малый угол, чтобы создавался эффект непрерывности. Для это можно использовать матрицу поворота (формулу Эйлера). Т.е. сначала поворачиваете на eps_0, затем на eps_1 и т.д. Так до тех пор, пока sum(eps_i) <= fi. Такой вариант пробовали рассматривать?

Comment: @hedgehogues, в этом то и вопрос.

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Comment: @hedgehogues, да

Answer (score 1):

Я рассмотрю частный случай, из которого легко следует общий. Предположим у нас есть 4 координаты 4-ка (можно обойтись двумя). Обозначим их

```
s_0 = <p_00, p_01, p_02, p_03>.
```

В Вашем случае эти координаты могут иметь задают, как сказано выше 1 из 8 состояний.

Необходимо повернуть наш объект из состояния `s_0` в `s_1` и сделать это плавно.

Сделаю небольшое отступление о том, почему не получается повернуть объект план. Если разбираться в причинах этого не очень хочется, то можно перейти к реализации.

Под плавностью понимается непрерывность в классическом смысле этого слова. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Чтобы чуть-чуть пролить свет на этот вопрос, поясню. Непрерывность -- это ситуация, в которой малому изменения аргумента соответствует малое изменение значения функции. Если это не так, то окажется, что у функции есть скачки (мы их, кстати говоря, наблюдаем в форме резкого изменения состояния объекта). В нашем случае рассматривается ситуация, в которой аргументом является угол, а значением функции -- состояние. Замечу, что должно быть задано некоторое изначальное положение объекта `s_0` (более детально этот аспект не буду обсуждать, про систему координат и другое).

[image: Положение объекта]

Таким образом, у нас есть отображение:

```
f = f[s_0]: Ф -> S
```

В таком случае, для решения нашей задачи необходимо, чтобы малому изменению угла соответствовало малое изменение положения объекта. Это легко обеспечить. Для этого необходимо выполнить серию преобразований на малый угол `eps`:

fs_0 = s_eps
fs_eps = s_2eps
fs_2eps = s_3eps
...
fs_(N-1)eps = s_Neps

Т.е. каждый раз выбираем некоторое начальное состояние `(s_ieps)` и переходим в новое `(s_(i+1)eps)`.

________________________________РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ________________________________

Рассмотрим один из возможных способов поворота объекта с помощью [матрицы поворота](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0):

[image: Матрица поворота]

В нашем случае, `x_i, y_i` -- координаты 4-х точек прямоугольника до поворота. В нашем случае, `x_(i+1), y_(i+1)` -- координаты 4-х точек прямоугольника после поворота. `eps` -- угол поворота (малый). Он выбирается руками. Полагаю, что 1-2 градусов будет достаточно `(eps = 2*(2pi/360))`. Теперь данное преобразование к каждой из координат необходимо применить `k` раз. В результате чего объект повернётся на нужный угол. Важно, что между поворотами объекта необходимо делать небольшую паузу, величина которой будет также влиять на плавность поворота.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот только я имел в виду не сам поворот а смену числа - угла в зависимости от направления, графическая библиотека сама поворачивает при отрисовке.

Comment: Что понимается под сменой числа угла? Хочется величину угла подбирать динамически? Почему нельзя его сделать просто малым?

Comment: Короче. Есть персонаж, не важно какой он формы. При нажатии клавиши "Влево" он должен плавно поворачиваться влево, но клавише влево это клавиша движения (Не поворота) т.е персонаж при нажатии движется влево. Но повернуться он должен коротким способом.Например если он был повёрнут вниз, то он должен не делать огромный поворот - сначала направо, затем вверх, и наконец влево, а сразу повернуться налево.

Comment: Я не понимаю, чего Вы хотите. Можете написать мне в скайп (IIFrodoII), мы с Вами созвонимся и я попробую вкурить, что нужно.